# How insert or delete row of JPanel consisting of 3 elements

Tags: swing, insert, jpanel, row, delete-row

I am using JPanel of three elements row: JLabel, JTextField, JButton.

```
jPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));
```

I need button of a row to delete its row from JPanel.

```
    for(Pair<JLabel, JTextField> pair: labelTextFieldPairs) {
        jPanel.add(pair.getFirst());
        jPanel.add(pair.getSecond());
        jPanel.add(createDeleteButton());//how to implement that method?
    }
```

Also I have a button to add row to JPanel.

How to do that? Or is it better to use JTable for that?

What if I need to insert row consisting of 3 elements somewhere in the middle of JPanel. How to do that?

```
    JButton addNumberToListButton = new JButton("add number to list");
    addNumberToListButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {          
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Pair<JLabel, JTextField> pair = new Pair<>(new JLabel(), new JTextField());
            labelTextFieldPairs.add(pair);

            jPanel.add(pair.getFirst(), labelTextFieldPairs.size()); 
            jPanel.add(pair.getSecond(), labelTextFieldPairs.size());
            jPanel.add(createDeleteButton(), labelTextFieldPairs.size());
//will this 3 lines work?
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post some code samples?

Comment: I've posted some code but i think it won't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deletion operation looks like this:

```
public void removeRow(int firstComponentInRow) {
    labelTextFieldPairs.remove(firstComponentInRow / numberOfColumns);
    jPanel.remove(firstComponentInRow);
    jPanel.remove(firstComponentInRow);
    jPanel.remove(firstComponentInRow);
    jPanel.revalidate();
    jPanel.repaint();
}
```

and add operation looks like this:

```
public void addRow(Pair<JLabel, JFormattedTextField> labelAndTextField) {
    labelTextFieldPairs.add(labelAndTextField);
    jPanel.add(labelAndTextField.getFirst(), (labelTextFieldPairs.size() - 1) * numberOfColumns);
    jPanel.add(labelAndTextField.getSecond(), (labelTextFieldPairs.size() - 1) * numberOfColumns + 1);
    jPanel.add(createDeleteButton((labelTextFieldPairs.size() - 1) * numberOfColumns), (labelTextFieldPairs.size() - 1) * numberOfColumns + 2);
    jPanel.revalidate();
    jPanel.repaint();
}
```

where labelTextFieldPairs.size() used as insertion index.